# How do I check if input box is focused with jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, focus, onfocus

Is it possible to check if a input box is selected by a user?

My html is:

```
<input type="text" name="fname"value=""id="name">
```

Could you do something like this?

```
if ($("#name").is(":focus")) {
//do something if focused
}
```

This exact method doesn't work but is there another way similar?

I am using the latest version of Jquery

Comment: No if, just `$('#name').focus(function(){ /* do stuff here */})`. Of course, I don't think you should use jQuery these days.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that

Comment: unfortunately it still doesn't work

Comment: Post a [mcve], as it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $("#name").focus(function(){
       //Code here
    });
});
```

If this doesn't work ^^
My guess is that jQuery isn't initialized in your HTML document correctly or your script tag isn't at the bottom of your body tag.

Example: https://codepen.io/HenrikDK/pen/NWGpPbK